# Having an issue with Awk where it gathers a number that does not exist in the log file I am using

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I am working on a log analyzer that is supposed to take the last two hours worth of logs and put them into a file when run.

I found the following example on a different stack exchange answer which used the following log type was used:

```
172.16.0.3 - - [31/Mar/2002:19:30:41 +0200] "GET
```

The example used to solve this particular log type was:

```
# this variable you could customize, important is convert to seconds. 
# e.g 5days=$((5*24*3600))
x=$((5*60))   #here we take 5 mins as example

# this line get the timestamp in seconds of last line of your logfile
last=$(tail -n1 logFile|awk -F'[][]' '{ gsub(/\//," ",$2); sub(/:/," ",$2); "date +%s -d \""$2"\""|getline d; print d;}' )

#this awk will give you lines you needs:
awk -F'[][]' -v last=$last -v x=$x '{ gsub(/\//," ",$2); sub(/:/," ",$2); "date +%s -d \""$2"\""|getline d; if (last-d<=x)print $0 }' logFile
```

I then modified this to suit my time format, which is:

```
10:51:53.762450 IP 151.101.193.69.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.52876: Flags [.], ack 507, win 324, length 0
```

After some manipulation, I removed the unnecessary awk code for things like [] and /, at least as far as I could tell, and changed from $2 to $1 when I noticed an output of `date: invalid date ‘IP’`
The issue is when I run my code, I get the following output:

```
awk: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'
pass
1651417024
awk: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'
```

This uses the example log snippet but I cannot figure out how it gets this number.
The code I am using is:

```
#!/bin/bash

truncate -s 0 twoHour.log

# this variable you could customize, important is convert to seconds. 
# e.g 5days=$((5*24*3600))
x=$((2*60*60))   #here we take 5 mins as example

# this line get the timestamp in seconds of last line of your logfile
#for the awk part, it outputs the date in seconds
last=$(tail -n1 tcpsample.log|awk -F'\.' '{ "date +%s"|getline d; print d;}' )
echo "pass"
echo $last

#this awk will give you lines you needs:
awk -F'\.' -v last=$last -v x=$x '{ "date +%s -d \""$1"\""|getline d; if (last-d<=x)print $0 }' twoHour.log
```

And a sample log snippet is:

```
10:51:50.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.35130: Flags [S.], seq 3706520983, ack 1064868235, win 65535, options [mss 1338,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 10], length 0
10:51:50.896364 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.35130 > 104.16.42.63.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, length 0
10:51:50.897189 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.35130 > 104.16.42.63.https: Flags [P.], seq 1:518, ack 1, win 502, length 517
10:51:50.903428 IP 104.16.42.63.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.35130: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 518, win 502, length 0
10:51:51.094584 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.53527 > 192.168.48.7.domain: 5779+ [1au] PTR? 114.201.96.52.in-addr.arpa. (55)
10:51:51.305306 IP 192.168.48.7.domain > term-IdeaPad-Flex.53527: 5779 NXDomain 0/1/1 (141)
10:51:51.305669 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.53527 > 192.168.48.7.domain: 5779+ PTR? 114.201.96.52.in-addr.arpa. (44)
10:51:51.309114 IP 192.168.48.7.domain > term-IdeaPad-Flex.53527: 5779 NXDomain 0/1/0 (130)
10:51:51.309982 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.56047 > 192.168.48.7.domain: 20119+ [1au] PTR? 18.242.247.162.in-addr.arpa. (56)
10:51:51.510273 IP 192.168.48.7.domain > term-IdeaPad-Flex.56047: 20119 1/0/1 PTR bam-6.nr-data.net. (87)
10:51:51.919820 IP 162.159.134.234.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.39586: Flags [P.], seq 1822:1877, ack 1, win 91, length 55
10:51:51.919863 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.39586 > 162.159.134.234.https: Flags [.], ack 1877, win 6245, length 0
10:51:52.738739 IP 52.96.79.82.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.36786: Flags [P.], seq 2962633948:2962633985, ack 1033019835, win 16385, length 37
10:51:52.738783 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.36786 > 52.96.79.82.https: Flags [.], ack 37, win 564, length 0
10:51:53.142449 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.58558 > 192.168.48.7.domain: 50837+ [1au] PTR? 82.79.96.52.in-addr.arpa. (53)
10:51:53.147047 IP 162.159.134.234.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.39586: Flags [P.], seq 1877:1921, ack 1, win 91, length 44
10:51:53.147091 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.39586 > 162.159.134.234.https: Flags [.], ack 1921, win 6245, length 0
10:51:53.353085 IP 192.168.48.7.domain > term-IdeaPad-Flex.58558: 50837 NXDomain 0/1/1 (139)
10:51:53.353282 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.58558 > 192.168.48.7.domain: 50837+ PTR? 82.79.96.52.in-addr.arpa. (42)
10:51:53.360629 IP 192.168.48.7.domain > term-IdeaPad-Flex.58558: 50837 NXDomain 0/1/0 (128)
10:51:53.482516 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.42192 > aeab55d76dd13c9bb.awsglobalaccelerator.com.https: Flags [P.], seq 1:97, ack 194, win 501, length 96
10:51:53.557493 IP aeab55d76dd13c9bb.awsglobalaccelerator.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.42192: Flags [P.], seq 194:236, ack 97, win 517, length 42
10:51:53.557541 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.42192 > aeab55d76dd13c9bb.awsglobalaccelerator.com.https: Flags [.], ack 236, win 501, length 0
10:51:53.557559 IP aeab55d76dd13c9bb.awsglobalaccelerator.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.42192: Flags [P.], seq 236:300, ack 97, win 517, length 64
10:51:53.557569 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.42192 > aeab55d76dd13c9bb.awsglobalaccelerator.com.https: Flags [.], ack 300, win 501, length 0
10:51:53.610272 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.42192 > aeab55d76dd13c9bb.awsglobalaccelerator.com.https: Flags [P.], seq 97:178, ack 300, win 501, length 81
10:51:53.659868 IP aeab55d76dd13c9bb.awsglobalaccelerator.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.42192: Flags [P.], seq 300:374, ack 178, win 517, length 74
10:51:53.659916 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.42192 > aeab55d76dd13c9bb.awsglobalaccelerator.com.https: Flags [.], ack 374, win 501, length 0
10:51:53.707200 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.52876 > 151.101.193.69.https: Flags [P.], seq 2882631170:2882631322, ack 3568058341, win 3785, length 152
10:51:53.707257 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.52876 > 151.101.193.69.https: Flags [P.], seq 152:507, ack 1, win 3785, length 355
10:51:53.762415 IP 151.101.193.69.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.52876: Flags [.], ack 152, win 321, length 0
10:51:53.762450 IP 151.101.193.69.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.52876: Flags [.], ack 507, win 324, length 0
```

If I can figure out how it is creating that number I can work on trying to get the script to run but so far my best guess is that it is somehow converting the names of the devices into numbers even though it should be working on only the `10:51:53.762450` part. The general goal is to go back two hours in seconds and save that to a file.

Comment: you've stripped out all of the `awk` code (`gsub()`, `sub()`, `date +%s -d`) that converts the last entry from the log file into epoch (aka, # of seconds since 1Jan1970) and replaced with `date +%s` which provides the current epoch; the `1651417024` represents your local date/time when you ran the code (`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d @1651417024` => `2022-05-01 09:57:04`)

Comment: if `last 2 hours worth of logs` is based on the *current* time minus 2 hours then `date +%s` is what you want though if the log file hasn't been written to within the `last 2 hours` then your script will generate no output; on the other hand if `last 2 hours` is based on subtracting 2 hours from the last timestamp in the logfile then you'll need to rethink your `awk` code (eg, go back and make sure you understand how that original `awk` code converted a date/time stamp to an epoch)

Comment: the original `awk` code was working with log entries that contain *both* a date *and* a time, but your logfile appears to only contain a time component; you'll need to come up with some logic on how to address a 2-hour time period that spans midnight

Comment: what does the first entry in your log file represent?  time of day? amount of time the parent process (that is writing to the log file) has been running? for example, assume the current time is `10:23:00` (10:23 in the morning) and I start the parent process ... what will the first entry in the logfile consist of ... `10:23:01` or `00::00:01`?

Comment: I see. The first part is time of day. The script looks through a saved log file, grabs the last entry and goes two hours back from there. I remembered that /*something*/ would be used in substitution. Looking back at it I probably still need the sub with the : but not the gsub accounting for the /. I'll look at it a bit more and see if I can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `date` for every line is expensive.

If you have `tac`, you can use awk string comparisons, with modular arithmetic and some simple logic to handle crossing midnight:

```
tac logfile |
awk '
    NR==1 {
        # extract timestamp
        now = $1

        # compute "2 hours ago" ignoring TZ
        nh = substr(now,1,2)
        eh = sprintf("%02d", (nh+(24-2))%24)

        end = eh substr(now,3)
    }
    $1<=end && ( end<now || $1>now ) { exit }
    { print }
' |
tac
```

This only handles going back up to 24 hours.

Assumes no daylight saving  timezone complications.

---

For example:

```
$ filterlog(){
 tac "$1" | awk '
  NR==1{
   n=$1
   e=sprintf("%02d",(substr(n,1,2)+(24-2))%24)substr(n,3)
  }
  $1<=e&&(e<n||$1>n){exit}
  1;
 ' | tac
}
$ cat in1
11:00:00. b
11:30:00. b
12:00:00. b
12:30:00. b
13:00:00. b
13:30:00. b
$ filterlog in1
12:00:00. b
12:30:00. b
13:00:00. b
13:30:00. b
$ cat in2
22:30:00. a
23:00:00. a
23:30:00. a
00:00:00. b
00:30:00. b
01:00:00. b
$ filterlog in2
23:30:00. a
00:00:00. b
00:30:00. b
01:00:00. b
$
```